# Android studio emulator keep starting up and nothing happen

Tags: android-studio, sdk, android-emulator

I try to learn flutter using android studio version hedghog(2023) but I can't run emulator and I don't know why because there is no error.
after clicking on start for emulator it keep stuck on starting up.
I try every solution that I found on the internet:

1. re-installing android studio
2. re-installing sdk
3. try new sdk
4. re-installing emulator
5. make new virtual devices

none of those help me

[image]

Comment: Hi Amir, I'm facing same issue, have you solved this?

Answer (score 0):

I've had exactly the same problem. The solution was to create another virtual device, with about the same characteristics. In my case, instead of "Medium phone", I selected a new "Pixel 7", along with the same API/Android versions as the previous AVD.